# 404 error with Angular 1.5 and Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings

For some reason when I try to run Angular 1.5 I get a 404 error. Also I am using typescript with typings to compile my files. I noticed that two angular.min.js files are compiled, one that has all the code and another one that is an empty file. The 404 error directs to the empty file.

This is my HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="app">
        <header></header>
    </body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

---

JS

```
    /// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.component('header', {
    controller: function () {
        this.header = "Hello World";
    },
    template: "\n\t\t<h3>{{$ctrl.header}}</h3>\n\t"
});
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

EDIT: I tried using a local file of angular but that made no difference.

Comment: Change the path `<script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>` to `<script src="./Scripts/app.js"></script>` . I think app.js is not accessible .

Comment: Thank you! It finally works!